# Token for Jira REST API

Tags: java, rest, jira

I don't have much experience with REST. Trying to extract some stats from my company Jira, and don't want to use JQL.

The question is, the token that I need to make the API calls, do I get it from my company's Jira or do I need to create an account with Atlassian and use the token from that account?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

Comment: Is this a cloud or enterprise instance of Jira?

Comment: @tgdavies It's an enteriprise instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create your own access token from within Jira when you are logged in.

From the Documentation:

- In your Atlassian application go to:

  - Select your profile picture at top right of the screen, then choose  Settings > Personal Access Tokens .
  - In Jira, select your profile picture at the top right of the screen, then choose Profile. Once you access your profile, select Personal Access Tokens in the left-hand menu.
- Select Create token.
- Give your new token a name.
- Click Create.
- Your personal access token is created. Copy the token and store it in a safe space.

However this might depend on your specific Jira installation. Your companies system administrators might have restricted this feature.

[Access Token Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/using-personal-access-tokens-1026032365.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Jira Server you could just use Basic Auth.

- click F12 on your keyboard => Console
  type in :

`btoa("your-username:yourpassword")`

A token should be generated, You can use it to authenticate with Postman or any other API Tool you might use.

`Headers: "Authorization : Basic ${token}"`

Jira cloud behaves different,

## Creating PATs in application

In your Atlassian application go to:

In Confluence, select your profile picture at top right of the screen, then choose  Settings > Personal Access Tokens .

In Jira, select your profile picture at the top right of the screen, then choose Profile.

- Once you access your profile,
- select Personal Access Tokens in the left-hand menu.
  Select Create token.
- Give your new token a name.
  Optionally, for security reasons, you can set your token to automatically expire after a set number of days.